# ¿Como puedo manejar este tipo de relaciones en Eloquent de Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

[image: Imagen]

Se como manejar las relaciones tipo "One to Many" pero al momento de crear una nueva venta, ¿Cual seria la mejor practica utilizando Eloquent para guardar?

Comment: No entiendo cual es el problema ahí muestras 2 relaciones `uno a muchos` que manifiestas saber manejar. ¿Cuál es el problema concreto?

Comment: ¿Cual seria la mejor practica para crear una venta?, como lo harías tu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Client.php

```php
/**
 * @return belongsToMany
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'ventas', 'client_id', 'products_id')->withPivot('id','date');
}

/**
 * @return hasMany
 */
public function ventas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Venta::class, 'client_id');
}
```

En Product.php

```php
/**
 * @return belongsToMany
 */
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class, 'ventas', 'products_id', 'client_id')->withPivot('id','date');
}

/**
 * @return hasMany
 */
public function ventas()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Venta::class, 'products_id');
}
```

En Venta.php

```php
/**
 * @return belongsTo
 */
public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Client::class, 'client_id', 'id');
}

/**
 * @return belongsTo
 */
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'products_id', 'id');
}
```

Lo anterior son las relaciones del modelo que muestras en tu imagen, mi respuesta es, utiliza la relaciones que necesites. De acuerdo a tu modelo, la venta de un producto se puede registrar así:

```php
$client = Client::findOrFail($request->user_id);
$client->products()->syncWithOutDetaching([
    $product_id => [
        'date' => Carbon::now,
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto Eleazar, pero como puedo obtener el id de la venta que acabo de crear.

Comment: Hola, ¿siempre que hiciste al respecto?, se me ocurre lo siguiente: `$ultimaVenta = $client->ventas->whereIn('product_id', $request->product_id)->first()['id'];`

Tienes una relación `hasMany` de client a ventas, entonces después de asignarla, tendrías que buscarla manualmente. `whereIn` acepta un número o un array, depende lo que necesitas si la ultima venta o las ultimas ventas, saludos.